# Rust: How can a reference be a type?

Tags: reference, rust

So what I am asking is, what is the difference between the return types, &std::vec::Vec and std::vec::Vec? Just curious. If I make a reference to something, I'm not creating a new type. It still retains its data and structure and so retains its type. But for some reason I get this error:

```
   error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/cam.rs:170:3
    |
168 |     pub fn index2d(self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Vec<u8> {
    |                                                 ------- expected `std::vec::Vec<u8>` because of return type
169 |         let c = &self.pyxels[y*WIDTH+x];
170 |         c
    |         ^
    |         |
    |         expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found reference
    |         help: try using a conversion method: `c.to_vec()`
    |
    = note: expected type `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
               found type `&std::vec::Vec<u8>`
                           ^ (umm excuse me?)
```

That one little symbol (&) really seems to make all the difference and I have no clue why.

Comment: Have you read through [The Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/)?  Given your example, it seems like you should make a point of revisiting Rust's concept of ownership. You'd most likely want your function to at least be `fn index2d(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> &Vec<u8>`.

Comment: No real issue here, I was just confused. I changed it to be `pub fn index2d(self, x: usize, y: usize) -> [u8; 3] { let c = &self.pyxels[y*WIDTH+x]; *c }`

Comment: I don't believe that would work with the specific code sample you've shown. You've also forgotten the `&` on `&self` still.

Comment: It compiles and runs, though I'm sure it could be improved.

Comment: You haven't given enough code to actually attempt compiling something, so it is impossible to say. If your return type is really `Vec<u8>` though, I don't think it's possible for `*c` to actually work. Please include a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on https://play.rust-lang.org/.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3cd493e930f979622b925a0e5bc5acc
 Here you go, since you asked. As you can see, I've opted not to do what I had before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I make a reference to something, I'm not creating a new type.

If by *"creating a new type"*, you mean *"creating an object of a different type"*, then yes, that's exactly what you're doing. A reference to a thing is not that thing. It's similar to the difference between having a house, and having a slip of paper with the address of a house written on it.

Though the syntax of Rust often makes access to an object through a reference look identical to direct access to that object.

```
let v: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
let vr = &v;

assert_eq!(v.len(), rv.len());
```

So perhaps that is why you are confused?

Comment: I think I get it. So when I pass something to a function, it literally needs that type, because some things will operate on references, and others will need the owned type. Otherwise crazy bananas stuff starts happening.

Comment: If a function expects a reference, you'd use the `&` operator to make a reference version of the value.